# Cannot auto update child values in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase

Does anyone know how do you automatically update the child values to the `tableView` every time it changes? I have to terminate the app and when restarting it I'm able to to see the updated values. How can I update these without terminating the app each time?

```
var ref: DatabaseReference?
var databaseHandle: DatabaseHandle?
var postData = [String]()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = Database.database().reference()

        databaseHandle = ref?.child("Posts").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
            let post = (snapshot.value as AnyObject).description
            if let actualPost = post {
            postData.append(actualPost)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

        })
    }
```

Comment: Are you talking about updating the cells? Use reloadData() to update the data inside the `tableViewCells` see more here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

that may work. Because all the UI-related works should happen in main queue